# Does the ratio between M and L cone cells vary in one indiviual?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, human-eye, color

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell#Shape_and_arrangement):

> The ratio of M and L cones varies greatly among different people with regular vision (e.g. values of 75.8% L with 20.0% M versus 50.6% L with 44.2% M in two male subjects).

This made me wonder if other people then can perceive colors more or less green/red than me. But then I asked myself why do I perceive all colors similarly for both objects on my sightline and at sides (except 90+° from my sightline horizontally). Is that because the ratio of cone cells is similar on the whole retina (in one individual)?

Answer (score 0):

The wavelength of light that appears unique yellow is surprisingly consistent across people even though the ratio of middle (M) to long (L) wavelength sensitive cones is strikingly variable.

Source: https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2531368